# Remove div if list has less than three elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

How can I remove `div.count` if the `ul.elements` has less than three `li`?

The html:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="element level-1">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="content">dsssd</div>
        <div class="count"></div>
        <ul class="elements">
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="content">assd</div>
                    <ul class="elements">
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="dssd">
                                <div class="content">dssd</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="fddd">
                                <div class="content">gfddg</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="fdff">
                                <div class="content">ddee</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="gfgggf">
                                <div class="content">hghg</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div id="gfgf" class="parent">
                    <div class="content">eeer</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="element level-1">
    <div id="hjjh" class="top">
        <div class="content">hjhj</div>
        <div class="count"></div>
        <ul class="elements">
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div id="yuyuu" class="parent">
                    <div class="content">uyyu</div>
                    <ul class="elements">
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="trtrrt">
                                <div class="content">trtrtr</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div id="opop" class="parent">
                    <div class="content">opop</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div id="kjkj" class="parent">
                    <div class="content">kjkj</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="element level-1">
    <div id="qwwq" class="top">
        <div class="content">qwqw</div>
        <div class="count"></div>
        <ul class="elements">
            <li class="element level-2">
                <div id="ytty" class="parent">
                    <div class="content">tyty</div>
                    <ul class="elements">
                        <li class="element level-3">
                            <div id="ghghgh">
                                <div class="content">jhhj</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the script:

```
$('.list .count').text(function() {
    var length = $(this).closest('.count')
              .next('.elements')
              .find('.element')
              .length
             ;

    if (length > 2) {
        return length;

    }
});
```

css:

```
.elements {
    clear: both;
}

.level-1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.count {
background-color: pink; float: left; padding: 5px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxD7W/)

Comment: What is your question? And please, don't say "it's not working".

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, I changed it to a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `$(this).remove()` to remove div in else part in your exisiting `text()` function like this:

```
  if (length > 2) {

      return length;  
    }
    else {

     $(this).remove(); // less than 3 remove it
    }
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/X99b8/)

or add another if:

```
if (length < 3) {

   $(this).remove();

  }
```

Comment: It made my day after a hours of trying!

Comment: I'll remember it for sure. Down vote was probably because it wasn't a proper question first. Best wishes!

Comment: It's not nice when people downvote anonymously and don't give a reason. I upvoted your answer so someone else must have downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.count').find('ul.elements').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('li').length < 3;
})
.end().remove();
```

**EDIT**

The following should work with the updated markup:

```
$('div.count').each(function() {
    var that = $(this),
        upUL = that.next('ul.elements');
    upUL.add( upUL.find('ul.elements') ).filter(function() {
        return $(this).children('li').length < 3;
    }).length === 0 || that.remove();
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/bmS23/)

Comment: @psot please see update code which should work fine with your current markup.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to selected answer: rather than removing the "count" entirely (in case you are live-updating the contents of those lists with JavaScript later,) why not just hide it?  Then you can display it again if the `length` situation changes.

This seemed to work:

```
$('.list .count').text(function() {
   var length = $(this)
   .closest('.count')
   .next('.elements')
   .find('.element')
   .length;

   if (length > 2) {
      return length;
   } else {
      $(this).closest('.count').hide();
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qxD7W/